# Spread Error in the two-way repeated measure anova test

Tags: r, tidyr, anova, rstatix

I am working on a two-way repeated measure anova using the rstatix package.

```
library(rstatix)

res.aov <- anova_test(data=kolding, dv=count, wid=id, within=treatment)
get_anova_table(res.aov)
```

And here's how the data looks like:

```
    id treatment           species count
1   K1    biohut  Goldsinny Wrasse     0
2   K2    biohut  Goldsinny Wrasse     2
3   K3    biohut  Goldsinny Wrasse     1
4   K4    biohut  Goldsinny Wrasse     1
5   K5    biohut  Goldsinny Wrasse     1
6   K6    biohut  Goldsinny Wrasse     0
7   K1    biohut      Atlantic Cod     0
8   K2    biohut      Atlantic Cod     0
9   K3    biohut      Atlantic Cod     1
10  K4    biohut      Atlantic Cod     1
11  K5    biohut      Atlantic Cod     0
...
```

I keep getting a spread error that each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys, and I don't know how to go about it.

I tried pivot_wider(), but it wouldn't budge.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: So take this subset of data you posted here and try to reproduce your own error. Cant? How you expect anyone else to help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `id` variable is reused for different individuals — ie, you have `K1`, `K2`, etc, for both goldsinny wrasse and Atlantic cod. You can make a unique identifier by `paste()`ing `id` and `species`.

```
library(rstatix)

kolding$unique_id <- paste(kolding$id, kolding$species)

res.aov <- anova_test(data=kolding, dv=count, wid=unique_id, within=treatment)
get_anova_table(res.aov)
```

```
ANOVA Table (type III tests)

     Effect DFn DFd    F     p p<.05   ges
1 treatment   1  10 0.45 0.518       0.034
```

*Example data:*

OP’s sample data initially threw an error because it only includes one level of `treatment`, so I added another level:

```
set.seed(13)

kolding <- rbind(
  kolding, 
  transform(
    kolding, 
    treatment = "control", 
    count = sample(0:2, 11, replace = TRUE)
  )
)
```